# How to list out the work items under a team in azure devops

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I was successfully able to fetch the workitems under a project using the below http request.

```
http://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/reporting/workitemrevisions?includeLatestOnly=true&api-version=5.0-preview.2
```

Similarly, i need to fetch the team workitems, this is the request i had used.

```
http://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/wit/reporting/workitemrevisions?includeLatestOnly=true&api-version=5.0-preview.2
```

But, i am not getting the workitems.
Can anyone help me with the syntax.

Comment: Did you below request url work for you? You can accept it as answer if it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the work items on a team's Taskboard with:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/taskboardworkitems/{iterationId}?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

and on a team Iteration with:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations/{iterationId}/workitems?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

You could also do a WIQL query:

```
    $AreaPath = "{Project}\{PathYou'reInterestedIn}"

    # Example WIQL gets all User Stories and Bugs that are not removed
    $wiql = @"
        SELECT 
            [System.Id]
        FROM workitems
        WHERE
            [System.TeamProject] = '$($AreaPath.Split("\")[0])'
            AND [System.AreaPath] UNDER '$($AreaPath.Replace("\", "\\"))'
            AND [System.State] <> 'Removed'
            AND [System.WorkItemType] IN ('User Story', 'Bug')
        ORDER BY [System.ChangedDate] DESC
"@

    $uri = "https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=6.1-preview.2"
    # add your access token to the headers
    $headers = @{ Authorization = "Basic " + + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$YourAccessTokenValue"))

    # I wrote the WIQL to be readable - this makes it suitable for a JSON request
    $query = @{ query = ($wiql.split([System.Environment]::NewLine) | `
        ForEach-Object { "$($_.Trim())" }) -join " " } | `
        ConvertTo-Json

    $workItemList = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method Post -Body $query).workItems
```

Comment: can you tell me the http request based on area id, how can i pull the workitems

Comment: It's the area *path* you would use, and you get to that by `Project Settings` -> `Teams` -> `Choose Team` -> `Iterations and area paths` -> `Areas`

Comment: Yes, how work items can be pulled using the area id in the http request.

Comment: or even area path also should work, but i need the query in the form of http request

Comment: The answer above does that - it creates a WIQL query that references the area path, then submits it in the body of the HTTP request.